# Validation by neighbor association attribute in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, associations

I have two models: **Parent** and **Child**, and i have a nested form for **Parent**, something like this:

```
= simple_form_for @parent do |form|
  = form.input :name
  = form.simple_fields_for :children do |children_form|
    = children_form.input :money
  = form.button :submit
```

What i need is a way to validate if sum of all children money equals to 100.

I've tried (in Parent):

```
validate do
  total = children.inject(0) { |sum, child| child.money }

  unless money == 100
    children.each do |child|
      child.errors.add(:money, :invalid)
    end
  end
end
```

but its not working for some reason. Thanks

**Update:**

Sorry, false alarm, i've used inject incorrectly.

```
total = children.inject(0) { |sum, child| sum + child.money }
```

Comment: How does it behave exactly?

Comment: ohhh. i'm so sorry, i've used inject incorrectly. its:
children.inject(0) { |sum, child| sum + child.money }